# JavaScript Filter() function with multiple parameters or keywords

Tags: javascript

I have one object of list of products and I have created one array to apply filter function to get parameter from that array. Like below

```
var selectedProducts = ['music', 'dance']
var products = [
    {
        ID : 1,
        name : "pro1",
        category : "music"
    },
    {
        ID : 2,
        name : "pro2",
        category : "yoga"
    },
    {
        ID : 3,
        name : "pro3",
        category : "music"
    },
    {
        ID : 4,
        name : "pro4",
        category : "dance"
    },
]

function filterFunction(){
    return products.filter((abc) => {
        selectedProducts.forEach(function(item, index){
            return abc.category == selectedProducts[index]
        });
    });
}
```

What I am trying to do is when user select any checkbox, selected values will be stored in selectedProducts[] array and then on those values filter function will be called and array will be passed as paramater with forEach method. Code works fine on each iteration of loop but at the end it return me empty array of object. Is anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Returning `true` from your `forEach()` loop's callback function will not have any effect on the filter condition.

Here's an alternative approach using [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/inc):

```
products.filter(({category}) => selectedProducts.includes(category));
```

**Full snippet:**

```js
const selectedProducts = ['music', 'dance']
const products = [
    {
        ID : 1,
        name : "pro1",
        category : "music"
    },
    {
        ID : 2,
        name : "pro2",
        category : "yoga"
    },
    {
        ID : 3,
        name : "pro3",
        category : "music"
    },
    {
        ID : 4,
        name : "pro4",
        category : "dance"
    },
]

function filterFunction(){
    return products.filter(({category}) => selectedProducts.includes(category));
}

console.log(filterFunction());
```

Comment: Also worth noting that even if it did, returning on every iteration of the loop will not result in the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Use the combination of `filter` and `some`:

```
function filterFunction(){
    return products.filter((abc) => {
        return selectedProducts.some(function(category){
            return abc.category === category;
        });
    });
}
```

`some()` function return `true` if at least one of `selectedProducts` matches with `category` of `abc`.

We also can use `includes`:

```
function filterFunction(){
    return products.filter((abc) => {
        return selectedProducts.includes(abc.category);
    });
}
```

When developing the frontend web, I prefer to use the combination of `filter` and `some`, because these functions are supported wider than `includes` (work with more browser versions).

Refs:

[Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/vi/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

[Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/vi/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

[Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/vi/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)